# Concatenate Unicode Dictionary Value with Unicode String?

Tags: python, dictionary, unicode

I'm trying to append a unicode string to the end of each value in a dictionary...seems straightforward and easy, but I can't figure out how to do it -- this isn't working:

```
redefined = u'_redefined'
for key, value in FCFDdict.iteritems():
    value.join(redefined)
    print value
```

what am I missing?  Feedack is greatly appreciated!!!

edit: my values are unicode file paths.

Comment: could you show the sample of `FCFdict`

Comment: What do you mean by it _isn't working_? What is the exception it is thowing?

Comment: no exception is being thrown, but my dictionary values aren't changing.

Comment: @CrazyOtto are all the value `unicode ` since joining may throw error if not

Comment: @Vignesh, yes all values are unicode

Answer (score 3):

This isn't what `str.join` does. `str.join` is for creating a single string from a list of string values. Here's what it would do with two strings:

```
>>> value = u"value"
>>> redefined = u"redefined"
>>> value.join(redefined)
u'rvalueevaluedvalueevaluefvalueivaluenvalueevalued'
```

Also since strings are immutable, you can't modify them. Instead you need to replace the value held in your dictionary. This would work:

```
redefined = u'_redefined'
for key, value in FCFDdict.iteritems():
    FCFDdict[key] = value + redefined
    print FCFDdict[key]
```

Using string concatenation (with `+`) is all you need, regardless of whether it's a unicode string or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
FCFDdict2 = {key: value + redefined for key, value in FCFDdict.iteritems()}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
redefined = u'_redefined'
for key, value in FCFDdict.iteritems():
    FCFDdict[key] = value + redefined
    print FCFDdict[key]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> d = {"a":"1", "b":"2", "c":'3'}
>>> redefined = u'_redefined'
>>> for key, value in d.iteritems():
        d[key] = value + redefined
>>> d
{'a': u'1_redefined', 'c': u'3_redefined', 'b': u'2_redefined'}
```